# PTV_Mercator correctly recalculated to WGS84 EPGS:4326 but not correct on map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, csv, overlapping-features

I have recalculated PTV_Mercator (PTV Spherical Mercator EPSG:505456) coordinates to WGS84 EPGS:4326 coordinates in Excel. And when checking them on Google Maps they show up correct.

But after loading the CSV and trying to combine them with a map (tried several like OSM, QGIS, etc.), I can in no way get them to "overlap". I've read (and tried) the QGIS "Projection"-topic in the manual several times, but I can not get it to work correct.

EDIT:

As requested, I have added a picture of the problem:

[image: Issue]
The recalculation was done with the use of this code-snippet:

[image]

Comment: Other than OSM, what have you tried? And what "Projection" manual? For OSM? Or something else?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. The manual mentioned was the QGis-manual. I have also used geo-data from PDOK (Dutch open source geo-data. Grtz,

Comment: Can you give an example of PTV coordinates, the WGS84 latlon you calculated, and where they appear on OSM background? You can still edit your question and add a screenshot.

Comment: Based on [this](https://gist.github.com/oliverheilig/7029947). It looks like it's a spherical Mercator definition. What's the sphere's radius? Note: EPSG has no IDs larger than 32766.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a newbie mistake. When importing the CSV-data I switched the X and Y fields. For anybody who encounters the same issue:

X= Longitude
Y= Latitude

Sorry to have bothered you all, but I still want to thank everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: If I had a nickel for everytime I've seen this... ;)